# How do I create a pivot table based on a specific condition using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to make this particular pivot table using SQL Server, but can't get it to work.

What I have:

```
id   name          was_clicked        times
 1   CustomerA               0          654
 1   CustomerA               1           24 
 1   CustomerB               0          121
 1   CustomerB               1           12
 1   CustomerC               0         1203
 1   CustomerC               1           67
```

What I want:

```
id   name          views      clicks
 1   CustomerA       654          24
 1   CustomerB       121          12
 1   CustomerC      1203          67
```

Is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to get the result:

```
select id, name,
  sum(case when was_clicked = 0 then times else 0 end) views,
  sum(case when was_clicked = 1 then times else 0 end) clicks
from yourtable
group by id, name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ed37/1)

Or you can use the PIVOT function:

```
select id, name, views, clicks
from 
(
  select id, name,
    case when was_clicked = 1 then 'clicks' else 'views' end vc,
    times
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  sum(times)
  for vc in (clicks, views)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ed37/3)

Comment: The first example (aggregate function with case) worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

About as basic example of [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) as you could ask for:

```
declare @t table (id int, name varchar(10),was_clicked bit,times int)
insert into @t(id,   name,          was_clicked,        times) values
( 1   ,'CustomerA',               0,          654  ),
( 1   ,'CustomerA',               1,           24  ),
( 1   ,'CustomerB',               0,          121  ),
( 1   ,'CustomerB',               1,           12  ),
( 1   ,'CustomerC',               0,         1203  ),
( 1   ,'CustomerC',               1,           67  )

select
    id,
    name,
    [0] as views,
    [1] as clicks
from @t t pivot (MAX(times) for was_clicked in ([0],[1])) as pt
```

You always have to include *some* aggregate in the `PIVOT` expression, since there *could* be multiple matching rows which should end up in the same column and row position in the result set. When *you* happen to know that only one is possible, the choice between `MIN`, `MAX` and `SUM` is somewhat arbitrary.

I tend to default to using `MIN` or `MAX` since its applicable to non-numeric types as well.